# Privileges to call a pipelined function inside a package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a pipelined function created outside a package which I can call like this and successfully returns the desired output:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ( TABLE ( my_function() ) );
```

However, if I try to create inside a package and try to call it, the below error message is raised.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ( TABLE ( my_package.my_function() ) );



ORA-64610: bad depth indicator
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_CALL_STACK", line 19
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE", line 3
64610. 00000 - "bad depth indicator"
*Document: NO
*Cause: There was no subprogram, error, or backtrace at the specified stack
depth.
*Action: Specify a depth for which there is a subprogram, error,
or backtrace.
```

What privileges do I need to make this work?

DB version would be: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Which database version is it?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production @Littlefoot

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include [MRE] with: the `CREATE FUNCTION` and `CREATE PACKAGE` code that generates the error; the `CREATE TABLE` statements required by the function/package; a way of generating a representative call stack; and your expected output.

Comment: `ORA-64610` indicates that you are using `SYS.UTL_CALL_STACK` and providing a non-existent stack position (i.e. a stack depth that is invalid as it is too deep).

Comment: There is a bug in 12c that raises that error; have a look at My Oracle Support document 2419817.1, maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: @MT0 I am not able to replicate it in a test package to provide a MRE, it seems to be related to the production package I'm using. I am absolutely clueless.

Comment: @Littlefoot I cannot access the document :( Do you have an extract of what it is saying so I can take a look?

Comment: @JaviTorre The 2419817.1 says:
Download and apply the patch for the internal Bug 27529661
or avoid call to ``utl_call_stack.backtrace_unit()``. Next is an example of how to do your own ``display_backtrace`` procedure using ``UTL_CALL_STACK.error_depth``, ``UTL_CALL_STACK.error_number(i)`` and ``UTL_CALL_STACK.error_msg(i)`` and sample how to use ``EXCEPTION when others then`` to avoid the leakage out of your code.

Comment: @JaviTorre - why can't you access the document? I know **I** can't, because I am not a paying Oracle customer. That's because I don't work in the field, I am just an amateur working on the Oracle db for my own amusement. But why do **you** not have access to MOS? Note that what David Lukas did (copying and pasting from MOS) is likely a violation of his Oracle license.

Comment: What do privileges have to do with the issue?

Comment: 2419817.1 says the error is related to utl_call_stack.backtrace_unit(). It doesn't mention pipelined functions. Does your function use it? @mathguy often in large organisations, Oracle Support Identifiers are reserved for the DBA teams and are not shared with developers. I can only access the My Oracle Support site because I have a free Oracle Cloud account in my own name.